# Get same data to different firebase node

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

In my ionic2 app i have to show same firebase data from different nodes.

[image: image here]

so here is my code in page.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RankviewPage');
     this.students=this.studentservice.getlastmonthexamusers();
  }
```

and this is the code in student service

```
getlastmonthexamusers(){
   this.examstudents=this.af.database.list('/userss/');
      return this.examstudents;
  }
```

In attendance node there are same users and it includes only the key in users node.I need to display these data also with the user details.

Can anyone save my day?

app is in ionic2 angular2

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Do you want them in the same Observable, would combineLatest work for you?

Comment: @Daniels I need to show the data in attendance also in a list, with details that includes in userss node.problem is to do that how to get data in the USERSS node to ATTENDANCE  node that shown by the key???    I knw by placing same data in userss node in attendance node can be use.but I need to know what is the properway to bind these two nodes

Comment: combineLatest + map / flatMap / flatMapIteratable should accomplish that. This is more of an RXJS problem IMO.